# Ipad crashes with appAvailability check for whatsapp

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, ipad, ionic3

I’m developing an app with ionic v3 and angular and I need to check for whatsapp in devices. We are using this lib https://github.com/ohh2ahh/AppAvailability. But only Ipads with iOS 14.5 make the app crash throwing this error:

[image]

the code is:

```
/**
   * Creates an instance of LoadingService.
   */
  constructor(private platform: Platform, private appAvailability: AppAvailability) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.checkAll();
    });
  }

  /**
   *
   *
   */
  checkAll(): Promise<any> {
    return this.checkAppAvailability('com.whatsapp', 'whatsapp://', '_whatsapp');
  }

  /**
   *
   *
   */
  private checkAppAvailability(android: string, ios: string, propName: string): Promise<any> {
    let app;

    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      app = ios;
    } else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      app = android;
    }

    return this.appAvailability.check(app).then(() => (this[propName] = true), () => (this[propName] = false));
  }
```

Comment: You need to run your app under the Xcode debugger with an exception breakpoint set to find the actual line it is crashing on. The exception message says that some code attempted to call then`length` method on `NSNull`; probably some value was `NSNull` when an array or string was expected

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11n!